# How the data range in different dimension will affect Gaussian Process fitting

Tags: gaussian-process

currently, I am using a `sklearn` GPR with `Matern` kernel. My input looks like `X=[x0...x5]`. And some the 6 dimensions will range from 0 to 4000 while some others range from 0 to 2. The code runs well, but I am not sure whether I need to scale all dimensions to same range. I have not found clear evidence to support or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should scale them.

We won't find "clear evidence" because usually, most applications are with a single feature in which case the range shouldn't matter too much as we optimise the length scale individually anyway. That said, with multiple features, it is not obvious what the distance $d(x_i, x_j)$ actually means especially when features are not normalised. In the case of unnormalised features, we might end up having a single feature dominate the others.

Comment: that make sense.  one more thing, will it make any difference if I scale up to [0,4000], or scale down to [0,2]?

Comment: Probably not. Unless we have very small or very big numbers and we shouldn't have any numerical issues. The big linear algebra routine is that Cholesky decomposition, so I would go ahead and check how that matrix looks like, very small or very large values would tip me going the other way with the scaling.